# How to drop privileges in a Debian Chroot?

Tags: linux, debian, privileges, chroot

I'm testing some software under [Debian X32](http://wiki.debian.org/X32Port). Its a chroot environment, and its entered upon as root. Some of the tests are [failing because of the root account](http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=4584&user=guest&pass=guest):

```
make test
...
# Failed test 'Testing that we aren't running as a privileged user, such as root'
# at ../test/recipes/40-test_rehash.t line 49.
...
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 5.
../test/recipes/40-test_rehash.t ........... Dubious, test returned 1
(wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/5 subtests    
...
```

Trying to drop privileges by su'ing fails:

```
# su - jdoe
No passwd entry for user 'jdoe'
```

How do I drop privileges in a Debian Chroot?

Comment: The problem is probably that the user does not exist in the new root. You should be able to create it.

Comment: @AFH - That worked. Please provide an answer so I can accept.  Any reason the Chroot does not use (or get access to) the user database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the reason for the error is that the user exists in the old file system, but not the new one that you have changed to with `chroot`.

If I knew exactly where all the user details are held, I could advise on which files and directories from the old file system should be copied / linked / mounted into the new, in order that the old users can log into the operating system running with the new root. I think most of them will be in `/etc`, but you can't just replace that directory regardless, as it will contain configuration data specific to the new file system.

Failing that, a simple solution is to create the users you want within the new file system. Since your purpose is to test non-privileged users, you do not need to reproduce existing users exactly.